# How napchart.com is constructed

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, github

I want to build a site similar to [this one](https://napchart.com/app).

So I downloaded the source code from https://github.com/larskarbo/napchart on my Windows 10 machine, but I don't know how to execute the thing and see it running in a page so I can play with the code and see how it is working.

- I have node.js installed but I am not sure of how to use it, so detailed instructions are welcomed
- Also, I tried saving the code from the site directly by clicking *Save As* but it didn't work though. Why is that happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering [napchart](https://github.com/larskarbo/napchart) has been pushed to the [npm registry](https://www.npmjs.com/package/napchart), you shouldn't need to interact with its source code directly.

As per your second question, I don't advise to download any of it manually. Running `npm install napchart --save` in your project directory should get you going.

That being said, the author also published the [source](https://github.com/larskarbo/napchart-website) of https://napchart.com/app, which can help you bootstrap your project.

Comment: Thank you for the fast replay

Comment: Do not hesitate to accept the answer if you found it useful